# PysimpleGui sin icono en barra de tareas al usar use_custom_titlebar = True

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica

Me he encontrado con varios problemas al querer personalizar las ventanas en Pysimplegui mediante `use_custom_titlebar = True`.

Mi sistema:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.1
- PySimpleGUI 4.38.0

Problemas:

1. No aparece el icono en la barra de tareas, solo aparece cuando
   minimizo la ventana. Consecuentemente, si mi ventana queda escondida bajo otra ventana de otra aplicación, no podré acceder a ella ni saber que se encuentra abierta sino hasta que haya quitado la ventana que se encuentra encima tapándola. Tampoco puedo acceder haciendo `alt+tab`
2. No puedo bloquear la opción de maximizar ventana. El parámetro `resizable = False` parece no afectar el comportamiento. Tampoco funciona si establezco un tamaño de ventana fijo con el argumento `size`

Agradezco de antemano cualquier aporte. Muchas Gracias

Código de ejemplo

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.B('Salir', size = (12,3))]]

window = sg.Window('My window',
                     layout,
                     use_custom_titlebar = True,
                     size = (None, None),
                     resizable = False)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Salir'): 
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: Hola ArielMdp, recientemente comencé a usar pysimplegui y me tope con el primer problema que mencionas. De echo formule una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/523141/pysimplegui-se-cierra-con-driver-quit-de-selenium) sin saber que el problema es en realidad `use_custom_titlebar = True`. Has encontrado una solución en este tiempo?